# Excel copy-paste: always match destination formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, formatting, copy-paste, paste

I use Excel to crunch numbers, so I usually don't want to copy the formatting along with the text. But this is the default. **Is there a way to default to always match destination formatting when pasting into Excel?**

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @Firee: Excel 2013

Comment: I maintain a free and open-source tool to enable [pasting plain, unformatted text by default in Windows, systemwide](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/ixm5bl/a_free_and_opensource_tool_to_enable_pasting). With `Ctrl+V` or whatever is the app's default for pasting. This mode can be turned off, and `Shift+Win+Ins` can be used as an alternative.

Comment: Type control-U (Mac) or F2 (Windows) to enter editing mode, then use the normal paste keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 42):

Can't set the default, but more convenient than fiddling with the paste options after each paste:

> If you press the Backspace or F2 key before pasting text it will paste
>   the text only, retaining the existing formatting.

source: http://appscout.pcmag.com/business-financial/272436-always-match-destination-formatting

*I wonder why this works?*

Comment: This doesn’t work for me in Excel 2007.

Comment: It works because it puts the cell into edit mode rather than text entry mode. It's equivalent to double–clicking in the cell.

Comment: If you are attempting to paste multiple rows, this will not work as it will put the text of all the rows into one cell.

Comment: In Excel 2013 you CAN set the default paste options, according to Microsoft. Options > Advanced > Cut, copy, paste. Adjust your defaults there.

Comment: Using the latest version of Excel, whatever that is in our 365 world, the options are pretty much useless for this use case. `Show paste options button when content is pasted`, `Show Insert Options buttons`, `Cut, copy, and sort inserted objects with their parent cells`. Nothing for stripping source formatting automatically now and forever.

Answer (score 24):

Simply double click on the cell first before pasting.

Comment: Note. To make this work you ahve to double click on the cell you are copying, select the cell text, ctrl-c. You can then paste anywhere without having to double-click on the destination cell. This will copy the text only and not the formatting.

Comment: This only works for pasting one cell at a time.  If you have many cells in a column, or many columns of a row, or any combination of that, you'd still have to copy and paste each single cell.

Comment: Thanks, but still not perfect way since you want to use keyboard only, then you need to do another action - press F2 to enter the selected cell first.

Answer (score 12):

Try <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> are the key strokes.

You could place a macro in your Personal personal excel workbook for pasting special, but you would not be able to undo the action after.

Comment: ALT+E+S+T+ENTER works for me. Your method didn't work, but I'm likely using a newer version of Excel.

Answer (score 10):

Paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to open a one key menu with formatting options. By default the letter is <kbd>V</kbd> to set the pasted information to the destination cell's former/proper formatting.

A little weird that the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, then <kbd>V</kbd> have such disparate effects, but nonetheless to past and keep the destination formatting:

Copy cell or range of cells, paste to new locations using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> like you would to move the source formatting, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>V</kbd> to select a change from the current source formatting into the destination formatting.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, then <kbd>V</kbd>. a much quicker method than point and click.

Comment: This answer needs more votes. It's closer to the objectives of the OP (quickly paste while keeping formatting) than most answers above.

Answer (score 9):

In Excel 2013, use the ordinary **Ctrl+V** shortcut, then press **Ctrl**, then press **M**.

Comment: Please elaborate how this answers the question "*Is there a way to **default** to always match destination formatting when pasting into Excel*".

Comment: @CharlieRB The answer to your reiterated question is, "No," I believe, but this is the best answer, even if it doesn't technically answer the question. (Many of the other answers no longer work.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a way to change the default. However, what I've found very convenient is to add the "Paste Formulas" button (which will automatically keep the destination formatting) to the Quick Access Toolbar. To do this:

- right click on the Quick Access Toolbar (the area in the top left with the Save, Undo and Redo buttons)
- click "Customize Quick Access Toolbar..."
- in the "Choose commands from:" dropdown menu, select "All Commands"
- scroll down to "Paste Formulas" and double click on it
- click OK

Now when you copy a cell or range, you can just use Alt+4 (assuming the new button is the fourth in the Quick Access Toolbar) to paste wherever you want and keep the destination formatting.

Comment: Thank you for this!  It works to paste multiple cells (e.g. a whole table from a webpage or something) AND it has a keyboard combo to activate.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to my answer above, there is one more way to achieve this.

Go to File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar.

Select "All Commands":
[image]

Select "Paste and keep source formatting", then "Add" the same. You can also use the positioning arrows to position this option to the top. Advantage of this is, to paste the item you have copied, you can use the shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> shortcut: (You don't have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with hitting "CTRL+V"

Comment: This seems to always keep the source formatting rather than match the target formatting, which is the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: @AdamV The "paste and match destination format" option can be found directly beneath.

Comment: The "paste and match Destination formatting" is no longer available in excel 365 Version 2302.
Sad, making this your ctrl+V shortcut would be the best solution. (there are only 7 paste options now)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN Excel PasteType reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel), there is no "paste-matching-destination-theme", although you *could* paste just the values or formulas.

Similar to the instructions found [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2545-excel-set-paste-values-as-default.html), you could add a macro to override the CTRL+V behaviour.

The steps are as follows (embellished slightly from the source page):

1. press ALT+F11 to open the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** window
2. select *Insert* > *Module* from the menu, and paste the following code in the **Module** Window:

   ```
   Sub PasteAsValue()
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   End Sub
   ```

   ***NOTE***: replace `xlPasteValues` with `xlPasteFormulas` if required
3. (*optional*) rename the module (in the lower left **Properties** pane)
4. close the window (click the "X" button at top right)
5. press ALT+F8 to open the **Macro** dialog box
6. select the "PasteAsValue" macro (or whatever name the macro created in step #2 has) and click the "Options..." button
7. in the **Macro Options** dialog box, type "v" in the box, and (optionally) any description
8. click the "OK" button to commit the changes and exit the **Macro Options** dialog box
9. click the "Cancel" button to exit the **Macro** dialog box (and avoid running and any macros)
10. save the Excel spreadsheet (Excel will throw a warning if the spreadsheet is not already an `.xlsm` "Macro-enabled spreadsheet" - click "No" to have Excel prompt for a different file name and file type to save as)

Comment: I followed this method however I was receiving the error: `pastespecial method of range class failed`. I replaced the VAB line with `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False` and that seemed to work. I got that line from recording a macro and performing a paste special text only.

Answer (score 1):

This is another work-around I have found, if you can switch from Excel to Google Sheets:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>: Paste values only

Source: [support.google.com/docs/answer/181110](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110)

I just double-checked, and Excel 2016 doesn't have this shortcut yet (by default).

Comment: Yes microsoft loves to fuck up the shortcuts with each version they enforce on users. I wonder if Microsoft's devs use their own products.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer, as an extended comment.

First, Microsoft have gone to extraordinary lengths to remove any trace of 'Paste and match destination formatting' in 2019, for reasons best known to themselves. I have to go back to Excel 2010 to do this.

Second, it seems that this can't be done for some data. If you have a value which is meant to be an elapsed time ('27.16', for example, which you interpret as seconds), then you can't paste it into a cell which is custom-formatted as, say, [m]:ss.00 (ie. an elapsed time, with minutes, seconds, and 2 decimal places), because you haven't got a number of minutes and a colon in the source data. This also seems to be a general problem with the destination formatted as an elapsed time, whether or not you have a missing field in the source.

Answer (score 0):

The paste forumula method works when one is copying and pasting into the same workbook.  When copy to a different workbook, choose paste special and then choose CSV format.

Comment: Gone in Excel 2019.