# Excel - Copy text from a web browser to excel without HTML format

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I paste some text from a browser into the Excel cell, it will copy the HTML format - colors, font type, sizes, into the cell as well. Is it possible to only copy&paste the plain text into the Excel cell?

Comment: did you try the paste special feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paste and match destination formatting

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can I make this "Paste as destination format" as default, so I can just use CTRL V to paste instead of right click on the cell every time?

Comment: It's OK, I found this thread
https://superuser.com/questions/683258/excel-copy-paste-always-match-destination-formatting

Comment: Is the screenshot from Excel2016?

Comment: **Try One Note**, Image to text , OCR: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-text-from-pictures-and-file-printouts-using-ocr-in-onenote-93a70a2f-ebcd-42dc-9f0b-19b09fd775b4